# How Javascript stores methods

Tags: javascript

Why is it that in Javascript, methods that relate to numbers are stored in the Math object? For example, to round you would need to do Math.round(5.2)

On the other hand, for strings I can just do “hello”.toUpperCase()
Why not String.toUpperCase(“hello”)

Like why cant we do 2.5..round() like how we would do "hello".toUpperCase() 
Is there a reason why things are organized this way?

Comment: One of your examples is math. The other is not. That's part of "organized".

Comment: math is an object, string is a function `String("hello").toUpperCase()`

Comment: @Rob Sorry I think to clarify, why cant they just put methods such as .round into the Numbers object just like how there are methods in the String Object. Like why cant we do 2.5..round() like how we would do "hello".toUpperCase() .

Comment: Probably to prevent ambiguity.  `foo.bar.round()` vs. `1.2.round()` sort of thing. How exactly would you resolve that?

Comment: This behavior is similar to other popular languages and it comes down to a number being a primitive (i.e. built into the language itself and not an instance of a class) and strings being a higher order data type.  Compare, for example, to C# ([Math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=netframework-4.8) vs [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8))

Comment: @c1moore but string is also a primitive just like number

Comment: @BrianBui Kind of, but not quite.  Primitive strings are wrapped in the String class when invoking a method on the String prototype: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects

Comment: @c1moore I see but there is also a Number prototype : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number
so why not put the round method on there instead of having to create a whole new class Math for the methods

Comment: @BrianBui Good point.  I can't say for certain, but I imagine the reason is twofold.  One, having a separate Math class mirrors other popular languages.  Two, as Crayon pointed out, it's probably to avoid potential ambiguity.  I'm not sure, but supporting the syntax you mention might affect whether or not JS is a [CFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).  That idea is somewhat supported by parentheses making that syntax work (e.g. `(4.5).toString()`).

Answer (score 0):

We can't do something like:

```
2.toString();
```

directly, but we can:

```js
console.log((2).toString());
```

This is suspicious to me... so i think javascript convert object literals in a specific generic type, something like String, and then makes the operation that is needed according the String method given.

In your example you said that Math object stores methods for making convenient number transformations, like parsing it to an int, parsing it to a float and etc.

But this is not exactly true, because we have also functions like:

```
window.parseInt();
window.parseFloat();
```

that are focused in.

And also we have the generic `Number` class which allows us to create a generic number as the java `Integer` which is different of java primitive `int`, so this clarify a bit what is going on here.

I think javascript have some methods for string and String and also number and Number but they are not the same, one is generic and the other is primitive, but... if this where true, the primitive objects should never have methods, so we can assume three possibilities:

- For object literals methods javascript converts the primitive object (if it's a primitive object) to a generic object and uses the generic object method, or uses an static generic class method.
- Primitive objects in javascript aren't primitive they are generic.
- Primitive objects have been constructed with some attached methods to it.

I will not make a confirmation about what is, because i don't know really if some of these posibilities are the right, but in my opinion i think the first one is the more accurate of how javascript stores and uses object literal methods.